# could not install any dependencies using NPM install ******, throwing error ( ECONNREFUSED, ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

**npm install -g create-react-app also nodemon failing and thrwoing error ETIMEDOUT**

not using any proxy
also tried reinstalling node often

all ready gone through several article on this but could not resolve the problem, what could be the problem ?

error log-

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'nodemon'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\sunil salat/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose npm-session 00ce03fa5818b313
6 silly install loadCurrentTree
7 silly install readLocalPackageData
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for nodemon@latest request to 
http://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 133257ms
11 verbose type system
12 verbose stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon failed, reason: 
connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
12 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
 12 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
 12 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
12 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
12 verbose stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
 12 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
 13 verbose cwd C:\Users\sunil salat
 14 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
15 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "nodemon"
 16 verbose node v12.18.3
17 verbose npm  v6.14.6
18 error code ETIMEDOUT
19 error errno ETIMEDOUT
20 error network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon failed, reason: connect 
ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
21 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
21 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
21 error network
21 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
21 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
22 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Did you check if you were able to open the failing URI (http://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon) in a browser?

Comment: yes i can open the url in browser@Aurélien

Comment: try pinging it through your terminal. use "ping http://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon"

Comment: yes , Pinging to registry.npmjs.org is successful, but  pinging  registry.npmjs.org/nodemon returned, HOST NOT FOUND

Comment: are you using any proxy? try running this `npm config delete proxy` if that doesn't solve just run `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/  `

Comment: @JatinMehrotra It should be with HTTPS, so
`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` but it's the default one, no need to set it.